# Change power supply to another battery

Tags: power-management, laptop, battery, thinkpad

I recently got a Thinkpad T470 that I installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on.

The computer has two batteries, one internal and one larger removable. My problem is that it drains the internal battery completely and then starts to take from the removable one. I want it to prioritize the removable battery first or drain them evenly.

I have installed `tlp` but could not find anything that helped me. Both batteries are detected by the system, but I cannot find any way to fix this. Is it even possible, or is it a hardware based problem?

Comment: You mean `tlp`, not TLS, don't you?

Comment: Most laptops in my experience handle battery load distribution in hardware -- but most will deplete the more easily replaced battery first (my Dell D520 would drain the bay battery before the internal, for instance).  Looks like Lenovo might not have considered the idea of carrying mutliple batteries to gain additional off-AC time.

Comment: That is an hardware issue. If you can't change this from BIOS or with  switch you probably can not.

Comment: You might check Lenovo's support pages for this model -- they make three batteries for the newer T series machines: internal, Ultrabay, and Slice.  Slice battery blocks the internal one, but otherwise, you can easily change either battery while the computer runs on the other.